# How to create a variable that will contain pointer to function regardless of arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I want to make Dialog handler for my app that will contain pointer to method that will be invoked when user answer "yes" and pointer to method for "no" and the main problem that these methods can have various args or without it so i dont know how to declare this variable.

```
class Dialog
{
protected:
    Dialog()
    {
    }

    static Dialog* singleton;

public:
    Dialog(Dialog &other) = delete;
    void operator=(const Dialog &) = delete;

    static Dialog *instance();

    string question;

    ?? method_yes;
    ?? method_no;

    static bool has_dialog();

    static void clear();
};

Dialog* Dialog::singleton = nullptr;

Dialog* Dialog::instance()
{
    if (singleton == nullptr) {
        singleton = new Dialog();
    }
    return singleton;
}

bool Dialog::has_dialog()
{
    return singleton != nullptr;
}

void Dialog::clear()
{
    if (singleton)
    {
        delete singleton;
        singleton = nullptr;
    }
}
```

So there is my class for dialog with user, when i want to ask user something i do

```
auto yes = []()
{
    ExitProcess(0);
};

Dialog::instance()->question = "Do you want to exit?";
Dialog::instance()->method_yes = yes;
```

And somewhere upper or whatever i have answer handling

```
if (Dialog::has_dialog())
// render question and buttons
// if pressed button yes
Dialog::instance()->method_yes();
Dialog::clear();
```

And what if for example i want to manage exit code so my lambda will be

```
auto yes = [](int code)
{
    ExitProcess(code);
};
```

But then there is a new argument so i cant just use

```
void(*method_yes)();
```

for declaration

Comment: C++ does not work this way. The types of all objects are fixed, and constant, and cannot vary. Your question is also very unclear, and hard to follow, and it's even unclear where the issue is. Did you take Stackoverflow's [tour], read the [help], and know all requirements for a [mre]? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: How do you expect the dialog box to provide the arguments for those functions? I would think a dialog box does "something" when "Yes" is clicked and "something else" when "No" is clicked and *has neither responsibility nor ability* to figure out arguments for those callbacks, so the callbacks can't/shouldn't expect to get arguments.

Comment: Let's say you have two functions, one that accepts arguments, and one that doesn't.   Let's say you have also set up a pointer so it can point at either of those functions and, at some point, you want to use the pointer to call the pointed-to function. At the call point, how would you expect to know if the function accepts arguments, and how would you pass them?  Bear in mind that calling a function that expects arguments, but not passing the arguments [and vice versa] (or even passing things of the wrong type) gives undefined behaviour in almost all circumstances.

Comment: What's wrong with setting a std::function<void()> member variable with a lambda that will provide the parameters as in for example `method_yes = [&obj, param2]() {  obj.call_me(param2); }; ` ?

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the day, C++ is a strongly typed language and you'll have to provide the set of expected possible arguments in your function signature.

Since you don't want that, there are some techniques to circumvent it so let's name a few:

1. The old (old old) `void*` trick from C. You declare your function pointer as

   ```cpp
   void (*fptr)(void* state);
   ```

   and then you're free to interpret state however you wish in your `fptr`, e.g. if `state==nullptr` you can assume there are "no arguments". Note that **this approach is not type safe** and can cause a lot of headaches if users don't respect the agreed upon protocol.
2. You bundle all your state in your callable and your function pointer becomes something like `std::function<void()>`. This way you can write:

   ```cpp
   std::function<void()> fptr = [code]() { /* ... */ };
   ```

   This is the nerfed version of the above, meaning your lambdas are now responsible for capturing the state you'd be passing to the function as arguments.
3. A pattern I'm using lately involves C++20 designated initializers  like so:

   ```cpp
   struct Argument
   {
       std::optional<int> code;
       std::optional<std::string> name;
       std::optional<float> value;
   };

   void (*fptr)(Argument arg); // Argument is elastic, i.e.
                               // it can be formed as:
                               // {}                 -> no arguments
                               // {.code=1}          -> 1 argument
                               // {.code=1, value=2.}-> 2 arguments
                               // etc
                               // Fields not mentioned default to
                               // nullopt, which means you have
                               // an easy way of telling them apart 

   int main ()
   {   
       fptr = [](Argument arg) { 
           std::cout << arg.code.value_or(0) << std::endl;
           std::cout << arg.name.value_or("no name") << std::endl;
           std::cout << arg.value.value_or(42) << std::endl;
       };

       fptr({});
       std::cout << "-------------\n";
       fptr({.name="Garfield"});
       std::cout << "-------------\n";
       fptr({.code=3, .value=3.14});
       std::cout << "-------------\n";
   }
   ```

   This is a type-safe alternative to (1). You declare the expected set of arguments in `Argument` but since they are optional you can call `fptr({})` and mark everything as "non existent" (the no args case) or even initialize one or more arguments explicitly e.g. `fptr({.code=3, .value=3.14})`. **Inside `fptr` you can inspect whether an optional variable is "filled"** and this gives you the freedom to act accordingly ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f12409aea8465f6e)).

If all this still seems unattractive, I wrote a post some years ago on how to [create overload sets out of lambdas](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/lambda-hackery-overloading-sfinae-and-copyrights/). Essentially the technique allows you to write things like:

```cpp
auto fptr = overload(
                []{ /*...*/ },             // A
                [](int code) { /*...*/ }); // B

fptr();   // Calls A
fptr(22); // Calls B
```

Again this means that all possible solutions (sets of functions of different types) are known at compile time, but you dodge the pain of creating that set explicitly.

Finally I'd re-visit the design before resorting to such solutions, maybe a simpler path exists e.g. express the exit functions as a hierarchy and have a factory method to generate the active function at runtime or even reconsider why should an exit function be tweakable at runtime.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it depends on non-standard language extensions.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Haven't you heard https://www.cppstories.com/2021/designated-init-cpp20/ ?

Comment: No I was not... yet.  Thanks.